# Button not working on Safari iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, button, safari

I'm having an issue, seemingly only on Safari on iPhone (possibly on iPad as well), where buttons are unresponsive. The other links work fine on the page (clickable icons, text links).

https://sedonaearthwisdom.com/winter-solstice-ceremony-2017/event.html

Anyone have any suggestions? I've searched around and nothing has helped so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Update: Now I have discovered that the buttons and text links are not working, except for the share icons that show at the top of the page. AND when one of these icons is clicked, then the rest of the buttons and text links on the page begin working... any idea what might be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? Thank you!